# Laravel - check if route exists not throwing exception if not found

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, redirect

I am trying to add logic that redirects old URLs to new ones by adding a prefix to the old url and checking if it exists in the urls collection and redirect if so. So the idea is we have old urls which now have been prefixed with a string but some would have already been sent to users so we would like to keep those working by attempting to recreate the url in the and add the prefix then check if it exists. The below is the code snippet used to create a route and match it if it is found:

`$route = \Route::getRoutes()->match(\Request::create($urlWithNewPrefix));`

The idea is that if the idea is that this code should throw a `NotFoundHttpException` exception but seems it still returns a route with uri `{fallbackPlaceholder}`.

So the current hack is to check if the uri is `{fallbackPlaceholder}` but a more clean way would be catch the exception.

Any ideas why the exception is not being thrown?

Comment: Could you show us the code where you have implemented this? I don't see where `{fallbackPlaceholder}` nor `NotFoundHttpException` is being thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have fallback router like

```
Route::Fallback(function () {
    dd('This is fallback function.');
});
```

So if the url not exist fallback route returned.
Try using something like this:

```
$route = \Route::getRoutes()->match(\Request::create($urlWithNewPrefix));
if ($route && !$route->isFallback){
  return redirect($route->uri());
}else{
  return abort(404); //or something else
}
```

*If that not answer your question give us more details

Comment: Can that second block go within the `Route::fallback`? I believe my match is failing (or succeeding depending on your outlook) because the non-existent route is being caught by the fallback.